# How can i make a simple chartjs chart with ethereum contract address

Tags: solidity, erc-20, frontend

i would like to have a chart on my site that prints the last price of a certain erc20 token

i have seen a widget from ethplorer but i rather build my own chart but i cant find any documentation for that.

so far i have this html code(the chart is a sample from chartjs) but i cant figure out on how to add the erc20 contract address

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-12 shadow p-2 mb-4 rounded bg-dark">
        <div class="chartjs-size-monitor"
            style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px; overflow: hidden; pointer-events: none; visibility: hidden; z-index: -1;">
            <div class="chartjs-size-monitor-expand"
                style="position:absolute;left:0;top:0;right:0;bottom:0;overflow:hidden;pointer-events:none;visibility:hidden;z-index:-1;">
                <div style="position:absolute;width:1000000px;height:1000000px;left:0;top:0"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="chartjs-size-monitor-shrink"
                style="position:absolute;left:0;top:0;right:0;bottom:0;overflow:hidden;pointer-events:none;visibility:hidden;z-index:-1;">
                <div style="position:absolute;width:200%;height:200%;left:0; top:0"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <h6 class="card-text" id="priceChart"> MONTHLY HISTORICAL PRICE +39.31%</h6>
        <canvas id="myChart" height="251" width="944" style="display: block; width: 944px; height: 251px;"></canvas>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
    var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
        // The type of chart we want to create
        type: 'line',

        // The data for our dataset
        data: {
            labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'],
            datasets: [{
                label: 'My First dataset',
                backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
                borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
                data: [0, 10, 5, 2, 20, 30, 45]
            }]
        },

        // Configuration options go here
        options: {}
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Can you please be a bit more specific? I think you want to interact with your smart contract from frontend?

Comment: no i dont want to interact with the smart contract i just want to make a price chart of the contract balance

Comment: how you are getting the last token price in your frontend code? please provide more details why do you want to add contract address if you don't want to interact with it.

Comment: through web3 and javascript- i do nothing with the contract address i just show the balance on the UI as Info. I dont know how to get contract balance inside a chart.

Comment: if you just want to get the balance of an account, use `balanceOf` function from the smart contract and pass an address to get the token balance for that account.

Comment: yes i know how to get balance of but i want to display the contract balance in chart form becuase the contract balance changes al the time and i want a historical chart for that

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`getBalance`](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.0/web3-eth.html#getbalance) method to get the balance of an address:

```
web3.eth.getBalance(address [, defaultBlock] [, callback])
// Example
web3.eth.getBalance("0x407d73d8a49eeb85d32cf465507dd71d507100c1")
.then(console.log);
```

Once you have balance, use it in `data` to plot the line graph as shown [here](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/line.html) and [here](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html).

Hope it will help.